# flash circuit in bird feeder

Tags: batteries

I'm using the circuit in a disposable flash camera to "discouage" squirrels from using my bird feeder. I've soldered across the charge button so it is always in charge mode but I've removed the capacitor and hooked up my perch leads where the capacitor was. The perches are wired  such that you have to touch two to get the mild correction. The problem is the battery runs down in a day. If I put a capacitor back in the circuit would that keep the battery from running down?

Comment: Does it flash without the capacitor? I would assume the capacitor is needed for proper circuit operation. Should be a part of the charge pump that creates the high voltage for the flash.

Comment: In a word, no. The battery runs down because of the losses in the circuit, not because there's no capacitor.

Comment: @DigitalNinja: We gave up on "proper circuit operation" when we disconnected the flash tube and hooked it up to a squirrel instead.

Comment: @DaveTweed Maybe I misunderstood the application... is op trying to fry squirrels? LOL

Comment: Shouldn't you put the Squirrel in place of the flash tube, not the capacitor?

Comment: If the battery's running down during the day, is that because you have too many squirrels?

Comment: I thought I might get burned on this one. I really wish I had chosen electrical engineering instead of fish and wild life all those years ago. Thanks for your thought full and comical responses. I'm just going to use a 1.5 volt supply plugged into the house. By the way, I touched both the terminals and was just startled not electrocuted.

Comment: Awesome project

Comment: Technically, the contacts on the perch could be thought of as a "parallel-plate capacitor" with very small plates and a very thick dielectric. As for "where is the power going?" @DaveTweed already answered that every bit as well as I could. ;)